# Spring Boot подключить CSS

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

[image: Структура директорий]

Пытаюсь подключить `css` в `profile.html` следующем образом

```
<link th:href="@{/css/profile.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Но ничего не работает.

**EDIT**

В браузере, если перейти по адресу, который указан в атрибуте `href` у `<link>`
получаю следующее 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Application

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

appication.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Что именно означает фраза "Но ничего не работает"? Проект не компилируется? При запуске падает с ошибкой?

Comment: Не работает `css` который я "подключил"

Comment: А эта фраза что означает? В html-коде сформированной страницы есть тег `link`? Если есть, то что у него в атрибуте `href`? Что происходит, если попытаться открыть значение атрибута `href` в другом окне браузера?

Comment: в атрибуте href в браузере "/css/profile.css" который якобы находится по адресу http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/profile.css, но такой страницы не существует, и по этому мои стили не работают. Я подозреваю, что нужно прописать какой-то конфиг для этого, но разве он по умолчанию не должен брать статические ресурсы из static?

Comment: что пишет в консоли? а другие файлы подключаются? дополните вопрос

Comment: Ну вот мы и подкрались к сути, которая в ошибке `406 Not Acceptable`  для url'а `/css/profile.css`. Показывайте конфигурацию.

Answer (score 1):

при такой структуре директорий

```
resourses
+-static
|  +-style.css
+templates
   +-project.html
```

у меня работала ссылка такого вида

```
  <link href="../static/css/style.css" th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

В [документации](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#a-multi-language-welcome) есть пример подключения CSS.

Comment: Судя по ошибке в случае автора вопроса Spring отказывается обрабатывать статику. Дело не в путях.

Comment: Не знаю как закрыть вопрос, но дело было в том, что у меня в обычном @Controller был метод, который возвращал json строку, уже не помню с помощью какой аннотации это сделал, и по этой причине всё приложение не могло обрабатывать статику.

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите в application.properties

```
app.storage.path=абсолютный путь до папки с проектом
```

И создайте новый класс конфиг. Я не подскажу как это будет на kotlin, но на java это выглядит так:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Value("${app.storage.path}")
    String appPath;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:" + appPath + "src/main/resources/static/");
    }
```